# Sony Alpha A6000 with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, camera, sony, ssdp

I am having trouble with the Alpha 6000. I want to connect to my Sony Alpha A6000 through Wifi but I am unable to do so. I want to write a small C# WPF app that can connect and communicate with my camera through Wifi. I am very new with this so I don't have a lot of knowledge but I am really eager to learn.

The first part that I am struggling with is discovering the camera through the SSDP method and I cannot find anywhere where someone has done this successfully. If I can connect to the camera then I would mainly like to retrieve the images on the camera through Wifi.

Another issue that I am having is that I connect the camera to the Wifi but I cannot find the camera's IP address on my network. With the Access Point that I have that my computer and the camera is connected to it shows all the devices that are connected to it with their IP Address and MAC address but for some reason it doesn't show the cameras IP address even if I give it a static IP.

Can someone please help me with any of these problems because this is really bothering me and I cannot find the right location for help or tips.

Comment: Describe your scenario(s) better. The normal setup is where the camera is the Access Point. It can also connect to another AP but I'm not sure if you can find it with SSDP then.

Comment: How do I setup the camera to be the Access Point because the only option that I can see available in the Network tab of the menu is the Access Point Set. which connects the camera to the access point.

Comment: On the camera, go to Apps and run the Remote Control applet. Or tap it with an  NFC capable phone.

Comment: I got that up and running and then also connected it to an Android phone. I am just now concerned if it is possible to put the camera in High Continuous Mode when I want to retrieve the images from the camera over Wif??

Comment: I can now find my camera on my wifi and I can ping it successfully. Where can I find the methods and details on how to communicate with the camera through the my Wifi?

Comment: I updated the camera now to version 1.2 and now I can find the cameras ip on my network. Where can I find the necessary information on how to communicate with the camera now with http?

Comment: I got hold of this project that people seem to use when they want to use the Sony Camera with a windows application. https://github.com/kazyx/kz-remote-api

Comment: Now I want to use this library but I can't find the proper method of modifying it to work with windows desktop applications as it is mainly written for windows phone or windows store applications.

Comment: I don't know that lib, but it mentions "Support desktop application". If it doesn't work out, ask a new specific question here on SO.

Comment: I have solved my problems with the Sony Camera SDK but now I want to know if it is possible to connect the camera to wifi and then retrieve the images off the camera through Wifi? And this without being in the Remote Control App on the camera because I cannot continuous shoot on the Sony A6000 with the Smart Remote Control.

Comment: Here is the link on SO where I asked this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531478/retrieving-images-from-sony-camera-over-wifi-ap