# Retrieving images from sony camera over Wifi AP

Tags: c#, camera, sony

I would please like to know if it is possible to retrieve images from a Sony Camera when it is connected to a Wifi Access Point on our local network? I want to retrieve the images from the camera with C# code.

Can anyone point me to where I can find resources regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what Sony Camera you are using.  See the Camera Remote API SDK page for more details on the API.  Inside the SDK you will find a PDF with a list of which APIs are supported for which cameras.

https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

Also, the Camera itself must act as the WiFi access point and you connect to it with the host device that you want to use to control it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but there are no public resources regarding it. See my answer to a related question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231367/how-to-connnect-to-a-sony-camera-via-wifi-from-linux/231433#231433).

Quoting myself (there's more detail at the link) - this is based on the Sony A7:

> The camera has 2 Wifi-connection modes: 
>   **(a) AP-mode ("Connect to smartphone")**, where the camera acts as an AP you can connect to. Only gives access to JPGs, not raws. API is proprietary but public (https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/)
>   **(b) Infrastructure mode ("Connect to computer")**, where the camera connects to an AP and pushes any files to a computer on the local network. Uses some MTP-flavour (based on PTP/IP).

So for (b) you would have to use or implement some kind of MTP- or PTP/IP-stack. You would also have to know the MAC-address of the computer the camera has been "paired" with previously.